# Log monitoring via Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I have Zabbix 3.x monitoring a particular log file on a few servers, with various triggers setup to match on certain regexes. In this case, while I want the PROBLEM notifications, I don't want the subsequent OKs for these log file based checked. Is this possible? I want the rest of the alerts to function as-is such as checking to see if processes are running or not.

Comment: If you disable recovery message in the action, does it do what you want?

Comment: Would that apply for only these log based searched or to all the other checks as well? Ideally, I just would like the recovery alerts for the logs just turned off, but have it remain active for the rest.

Comment: The recovery message checkbox applies to all events that the action applies to. If you wish to limit it to log files only, you should create a separate action and filter triggers in action conditions (by trigger, template or application).